# We've been promoted!

Tags: discussion

Congratulations to everyone over the past 4+ years who has helped keep this community going including, past and present moderators, queue reviewers, and most importantly all of the contributors! Your questions, answers, and feedback has grown our community and helped developers near and far. To all the DevOps engineers around the world, may your IAC be versioned, your monitoring be transparent, your pipelines fail gracefully, your deployments be idempotent, and should you need guidance, may you find a home of answers amongst your fellow DevOps Engineers. Cheers!!

[image]